# TextSwitcher switches very quickly on every reload with swiperefresh (Java)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textswitcher

I put a `TextSwitcher` (fully in `xml` file) inside a simple method as follow (a `TextSwitcher` that switches automatically every 2 seconds) and every time I refresh the page using swipeRefresh I don't know why it becomes faster. Why this happen and How can one fix this problem?

```
    TextSwitcher ts = findViewById(R.id.textswitcher);
    
    swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
            showSwitcher(new String[]{"NO WATER", "NO ENERGY"});
            swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                        });
    ...
    private void showSwitcher(String[] mArray) {
         final int[] idx = {0};
    
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        idx[0] = ((idx[0] + 1) < 2) ? (idx[0] + 1) : 0;
                        ts.setText(mArray[idx[0]]);
                        ts.postDelayed(this, 2000);
                    }
                };
    
                ts.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
    }
```

**swipe refreshing once:**

[image]

**swipe refreshing many times:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you refresh the page, you're adding a new runnable task without removing the old ones.
Can you try this.

```
Runnable runnable;
TextSwitcher ts = findViewById(R.id.textswitcher);

swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
    showSwitcher(new String[]{"NO WATER", "NO ENERGY"});
    swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
});

private void showSwitcher(String[] mArray) {
    if (runnable != null) {
        ts.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

    final int[] idx = {0};

    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            idx[0] = ((idx[0] + 1) < 2) ? (idx[0] + 1) : 0;
            ts.setText(mArray[idx[0]]);
            ts.postDelayed(this, 2000);
        }
    };

    ts.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
}
```

Comment: That worked! But I already tried something like this (not exactly) by putting `ts.removeCallbacks(runnable);` before `ts.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);` without global variable `runnable`. Why this is not same as yours?

Comment: You mentioned it yourself that you added the `removeCallbacks()` method before the line `ts.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);`  You also added it again at the end with `postDelayed()`. To make the `removeCallbacks()` method work correctly, you need to provide a valid reference. However, you defined and added a local variable within the function, so when the page is refreshed, you lose access to that variable. To avoid this issue, it's much simpler and safer to create a global variable and use it for control.